# Tooltip to be over the layout, scrollbar is hiding it inside. Z-index not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a layout wrapped with scrollbar component of react like this on this link: https://malte-wessel.com/react-custom-scrollbars/  this kind of scrollbar, and I need a tool tip to appear over the layout on the bottom when it is scrolling. Z-index does not seem to work.

I tried using z-index but no luck.

https://malte-wessel.com/react-custom-scrollbars/

What I need is this:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example of your code and what you tried so far?

Comment: @lilo, what module did you use to make a tooltip?

Comment: This is my tooltip https://jsfiddle.net/oyz3p8ks/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the position of the tooltip related to the hover

Change the css of the hover like this

```
.info__helper--withhover:hover {
  .text-inside {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 3px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Still goes under, It does not go above all elements

Comment: What do you mean? You have many elements with tooltip or just one like the example? We need more info if the question isn't clear